# Node text width surpasses margin

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've defined a command that creates boxes for definitions using tikz. However, even though i've set the text width to `\textwidth`, the right part of the box surpasses the margin. Setting `\inner xsep = 0pt` did fix my problem, but the text and the blue bar on the left would have no seperation whatsoever. And I could not find a way to shift the text to the right after setting `\inner xsep = 0pt`. Is there an alternate way to fix my problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in, a4paper}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\let\svtikzpicture\tikzpicture
\def\tikzpicture{\noindent\svtikzpicture}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\tikzset{definitions/.style={text width=\textwidth}}
\definecolor{defblue}{RGB}{50,100,168}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, backgrounds,fit,calc}

\newcommand{\altdef}[3][2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[definitions, name=defin]{ {\textsf{\color{defblue}\textbf{{Definition}} (#2)\textbf{.}}}
#3};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[name=bg, fill=gray!5, fit={(defin)}] {};
\filldraw[fill=blue, draw=blue] (bg.north west) rectangle ($(bg.south west)+(2px,0cm)$);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\altdef{Scalar}{A quantity whose value may be represented by a single real number. \underline{Ex:} mass, volume \ldots
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue  comes from the `fit` node.
When you write this: `\node[name=bg, fill=gray!5, fit={(defin)}] {};` without any `inner sep`, you create a node surrounding the `defin` node, with a default inner sep, hence the unwanted additional width on the right. Adding `inner sep=0pt` works fine. But I don't see the point in adding this node. You can fill your `defin` node and draw the bllue rectangle on top of it just like this (see code).

Now for the text width itself, it's better to compute it depending on the inner sep you set. Hence the line: `\tikzset{definitions/.style={inner sep=1em,text width=\textwidth-2em}}`. You could adjust the left inner sep if needed.

[image: node does not surpass margin anymore]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in, a4paper}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\let\svtikzpicture\tikzpicture
\def\tikzpicture{\noindent\svtikzpicture}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\tikzset{definitions/.style={inner sep=1em,text width=\textwidth-2em}}
\definecolor{defblue}{RGB}{50,100,168}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, backgrounds,fit,calc}

\newcommand{\altdef}[3][2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[definitions, name=defin,fill=gray!5]{ {\textsf{\color{defblue}\textbf{{Definition}} (#2)\textbf{.}}}
    #3};
    \filldraw[fill=blue, draw=blue] (defin.north west) rectangle ($(defin.south west)+(2px,0cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

    \altdef{Scalar}{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```